# Extracting Advanced Custom Fields' data all at once in a separate PHP file

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

Sometimes a single page uses dozens of ACF fields - for instance in the case of repeater fields. Dozens of ACF fields means dozens of `if (get_field('blabla') { the_field('blabla'); }` (among other ACF code) clogging up the page's PHP template file and making it effectively hard to read and maintain, I want to extract all ACF data into PHP variables for my template to use.

Problem: if I do that I'll need to declare all my PHP variables as global variables at the beginning of my template. Less ugly that the former, but still ugly.

Any alternative I haven't thought of yet?

Answer (score 0):

I think for repeater fields you can have a function for each specific task in same pages and call that function where required in the same file. For example:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div><?php call_user_func( 'who_weve_worked_with', get_the_ID() ); ?></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Now, you can have all the function in separate file like:

```
theme-folder/inc/acf-fucntions.php
```

It needs to be included in functions.php

```
<?php require get_template_directory() . '/inc/acf-fucntions.php'; ?>
```

For child theme,

```
<?php require get_stylesheet_directory() . '/inc/acf-fucntions.php'; ?>
```

Now, in the acf-functions.php,

```
<?php
if( !function_exists( 'who_weve_worked_with' ) ) {

function who_weve_worked_with( $post_id )   {

    ?>
    <div>      
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
            <?php
            if ( have_rows( 'repeater_field_name', $post_id ) ) :
                $i = 0;
                while ( have_rows ( 'repeater_field_name', $post_id ) ) : the_row();
                    $img = get_sub_field( 'repeater_sub_field_name', $post_id );
                    ?>
                    <li role="presentation">

                        <img src="<?php echo $img[ 'url' ]; ?>" alt="<?php echo $img[ 'alt' ]; ?>">

                    </li>
                    <?php
                    $i++;
                endwhile;
            endif;
            ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <?php
    }
}
```

Please don't forget to pass the POST ID while calling a function and your function need to have one parameter which is POST ID as seen above.

Hope this works for you.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks. That would work well if I needed ACF data all in one place within my template. The issue is I need to retrieve many ACF field values and use those in many different locations within my template.